# delete button for continuous access 2019 form with vba code for specific record in specific table without deleting other record in relational with it

Tags: ms-access

```
Private Sub delete_Click()
 Dim db As Database
 Dim sSQL As String

 Set db = CurrentDb
sSQL = "DELETE FROM  1مجمع نتائج الحجرات WHERE [م] = " & Me.Text96 & " ;"
  db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
MsgBox "Deleted " & db.RecordsAffected
```

Comment: If delete is turned in _Referential Integrity_ for subtables, records of those _will_ be deleted as well. That's a core purpose of defining RI.

Comment: I also have error 128 when i try to execute SQL command what is the error that I had in this code and I noticed deleting through the sub continuous form is deleting all thing but when I delete directly from the table its delete normally and safe how could I make command that delete specific record from my table directly but through a button in my sub form with condition come from textbox refer to the ID of this record that's the meaning of [م]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.a00b.com/Nw/insert_delete_update_in_vba.htm  running insert delete and update via VBA.